# Handling Arabic text in Python

Tags: python, arabic

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
mydoclist = ['جوليا تحبني اكثر من ليندا','جين تحبني اكثر من جوليا','احمد يحب كرة السلة اكثر من كرة الطاولة']

from collections import Counter

for doc in mydoclist:
     tf = Counter()
     for word in doc.split():
         tf[word] +=1
     print tf.items()
```

I got the following output:

```
[(u'\u062a\u062d\u0628\u0646\u064a', 1), (u'\u0645\u0646', 1), (u'\u062c  \u0648\u0644\u064a\u0627', 1), (u'\u0644\u064a\u0646\u062f\u0627', 1), (u'\u0627\u0643\u062b\u0631', 1)]
[('\xd8\xac\xd9\x8a\xd9\x86', 1), ('\xd9\x85\xd9\x86', 1), ('\xd8\xac\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa7', 1), ('\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd9\x86\xd9\x8a', 1), ('\xd8\xa7\xd9\x83\xd8\xab\xd8\xb1', 1)]
[('\xd8\xa7\xd9\x83\xd8\xab\xd8\xb1', 1), ('\xd8\xa7\xd8\xad\xd9\x85\xd8\xaf', 1), ('\xd9\x8a\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8', 1), ('\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd8\xa9', 1), ('\xd9\x83\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa9', 2), ('\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa9', 1), ('\xd9\x85\xd9\x86', 1)]
```

Why I can not see Arabic words. I want to see Arabic words instead of these codes that appear in the output. Thanks.

Comment: loop that array and print each item with filesystemencoding, and looks like you have unicode and utf8 encoding mixing, you may need some encoding conversions.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're stuck with Python 2.7? Especially when it comes to handling Unicode text, Python 3 wins in all aspects. However, there are some problems with rendering BIDI text; on my terminal all of the text gets rendered RTL: `[('تحبني', 1), ('من', 1), ('ج  وليا', 1), ('ليندا', 1), ('اكثر', 1)]`.

Comment: You are seeing the repr output, no matter what you do you won't be seeing the words when you print the dict. Loop over the dict and print each  key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python prints lists so that all items in them are passed through `repr` which in turn produces this stuff with "\u...". Also have a look at the tutorial section about [unicode-strings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) or better the [unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html) they helped me a lot.
For sourcecode containing non-ascii characters you should [set an encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) (most likely "utf-8"). Also you propably want to mark strings containing such characters as unicode (`u"..."` instead of `"..."`)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import Counter


mydoclist = [u'جوليا تحبني اكثر من ليندا',u'جين تحبني اكثر من جوليا',u'احمد يحب كرة السلة اكثر من كرة الطاولة']



for doc in mydoclist:
     tf = Counter()
     for word in doc.split():
         tf[word] +=1
     print u", ".join( u"(%i: %s)"%(n,s) for (s,n) in tf.items())
```

works for me.